# Adding to Additional Custom Methods to Custom RoleProvider ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, overriding, roles, roleprovider

I am working on a web application that uses "[Activity Based Authorization](http://ryankirkman.com/2013/01/31/activity-based-authorization.html%20%22Activity%20Based%20Authorization)."  Basically, instead of roles being allowed to do an action, a role or user has to be authorized for that activity instead.  I'm wondering if, on top of a custom role provider overriding the default methods, that I can add custom methods on top of those. I'm rather new to MVC and I feel like I'm going beyond my abilities, but I figure it must be possible.

For example:

There is a `@User.IsInRole("RoleName")` in Razor.

I'd like to add an additional method like `@User.AuthorizedActivity("Admin/Permissions/Edit")` (based off of the naming in my activities table).

Is this possible and how can it done?